# SQL Server match two columns by different strings

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime

So I have two tables:

**Expected**:

- Id
- numberOfItems
- date

And **Reality**:

- Id
- numberOfItems
- date

And I want to get, for each month, sum of `Expected.numberOfItems` and sum of `Reality.numberOfItems`.

The problem I have is that while `Expected.date` is a `datetime`, `Reality.date` is an `int` with a `YYYYMM` format. My guess is I need to match Strings so I got to something like:

```
select distinct(a.date) as expected, sum(a.items), sum(b.items)
from A a, B b
where a.date = [some manipulation](b.date)
group by a.date order by a.date desc
```

Would this be even legal? Is there any better approach? It looks like not good at all for me but I have limited experience with SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.date, [some manipulation](b.date)) AS expected, 
       Sum(a.items), 
       Sum(b.items) 
FROM   a a 
       FULL OUTER JOIN b b 
                    ON a.date = [some manipulation](b.date) 
GROUP  BY COALESCE(a.date, [some manipulation](b.date)) 
ORDER  BY a.date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query by converting expecting date also to int of 'YYYYMM' format using convert(...,112). If you are thinking many times you are doing convert then try using CTE where you can convert once and use it many times

```
SELECT COALESCE(convert(int,convert(varchar(6),expected.date, 112)), reality.date) AS [expectedDate], 
       Sum(expected.items), 
       Sum(reality.items) 
FROM   a expected FULL JOIN b reality
       ON convert(int,convert(varchar(6),expected.date, 112)) = reality.date
GROUP  BY COALESCE(convert(int,convert(varchar(6),expected.date, 112)), reality.date) 
ORDER  BY expected.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(a.date) as expected, sum(a.items), sum(b.items)
from A a, B b
where a.date = cast(b.date as datetime)
group by a.date order by a.date desc
```

You need to cast int to datetime using cast. That being said, if you can change the datatype of column, you should definitely do that.

Let me know if you need help with query as well, I will edit my answer.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Agreed, As mentioned in the answer, I have not changed the query but only given the answer of how to cast int to datetime

Comment: If I do it that way, won't I only get anything that matches at a specific moment instead of matching the whole month?